# Can anyone help me with the structure of array of localized attributes in the proactive events API when there are more than one localized attributes?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, proactive

I was playing around with the proactive events but got stuck at the localizedattribute thing. So I was using media content available schema and it has two localizedattribute, and I can't find an example on how to use two of them at once. Any idea? So basically, this works :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-01-25T08:41:01.00Z",
    "referenceId": "orangfdetango2221800f44-436a-4c47-8d9f-e14356bb010c",
    "expiryTime": "2019-01-26T08:20:01.00Z",
    "event": {
    "name": "AMAZON.MediaContent.Available",
    "payload": {
        "availability": {
            "startTime": "2019-01-23T21:00:00Z",
            "method":"DROP"
        },
        "content": {
            "name": "localizedattribute:contentName",
            "contentType":"EPISODE"
        }
    }
},

        "localizedAttributes": [
            {
                "locale": "en-US",
                "contentName": "Who Wrote the Bible? - 01/13/2019"
            }
        ],
      "relevantAudience": {
        "type": "Multicast",
        "payload": {}
    }
}
```

But not this because it has two localizedattributes:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-01-25T08:41:01.00Z",
    "referenceId": "orangfdetango2221800f44-436a-4c47-8d9f-e14356bb010c",
    "expiryTime": "2019-01-26T08:20:01.00Z",
    "event": {
    "name": "AMAZON.MediaContent.Available",
    "payload": {
        "availability": {
            "startTime": "2019-01-25T21:00:00Z",
            "provider": {
                "name": "localizedattribute:providerName"
            },
            "method":"STREAM"
        },
        "content": {
            "name": "localizedattribute:contentName",
            "contentType":"EPISODE"
        }
    }
},

        "localizedAttributes": [
            {
                "locale": "en-US",
                "providerName": "Lindsborg Covenant Church"
            },
            {
                "locale": "en-US",
                "contentName": "Who Wrote the Bible? - 01/13/2019"
            }
        ],
      "relevantAudience": {
        "type": "Multicast",
        "payload": {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, it was a simple fix, though I couldn't find it in any documentation.

What needed to be done was changing localized attributes to:

```
    "localizedAttributes": [
        {
            "locale": "en-US",
            "providerName": "Lindsborg Covenant Church",
            "contentName": "Who Wrote the Bible? - 01/13/2019"
        }
    ],
```